# jQuery form plugin duplicate elements after submit ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-forms-plugin, jqueryform

I am using jquery form plugin for sending request to server and write some data in database. After submitting form some elements like sidebar is duplicated. I set `target` to be container that be refreshed after successing. All work good but whay elements id duplicated.

```
<div class="contaner-fluid">
 <div class="sidebar_lft"> Sidebar </div> <!-- This sidebar is dupicated -->
 <div id="main-content">
      <!-- PHP forach loop some data. This div need to been refreshed after success-->
    <form id="user-form" action="user/update" metod="post">
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

**And jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#user-form').ajaxForm({
        target: '#main-content',
        success: function() {
            alert('Success');
        }
    });
});
```

All data is saved in database and all work good expect that reloading div. When ajax execute success callback he duplicate my sidebar idk whay.

Comment: `metod="post"` has a typo, it should be `method="post"` (missing `h`). How are you calling the jQuery code? It should be in `$("#user-form").submit()`.

Comment: it is post but this code i write manualy

Comment: Please edit your question to fix any copying errors.

Comment: And update the question to show where you're calling `.ajaxForm` from.

Comment: I update, its all u dont need html from sidebar]